# [Git]Hub change directory not working. What is the issue?

Tags: git, github

GitHub change directory not working.

I put in: "cd /C/Users/Anon/Desktop/Git_Ballsy", and GitHub (terminal) keeps throwing this...

```
C:\Users\Anon\Documents\GitHub [master +1 ~0 -0 !]> cd /C/Users/Anon/Desktop/Git_Ballsy
Set-Location : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Anon/Desktop/Git_Ballsy'.
At line:1 char:1
+ cd /C/Users/Anon/Desktop/Git_Ballsy
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Location], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice the backslashes your command prompt:

```
C:\Users\Anon\Documents\GitHub [master +1 ~0 -0 !]>
```

This indicates that you are using `cmd.exe` or PowerShell, not Git Bash (which uses forward slashes). The `Set-Location` part suggests PowerShell. As a result, you should use Windows-style paths in your `cd` command:

```
cd C:\Users\Anon\Desktop\Git_Ballsy
```